# Run function on page load (Refresh RSS feed with new URL) Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an app where I want to display different RSS feeds on one page, when the corresponding team is clicked.

For example, when I click "Aberdeen" I want the page to show the RSS for Aberdeen.
When I click "Celtic", i want the same page to display the RSS for Celtic.

I will attach my code in one section - basically when the page `#feed` loads, I need to run the `getFeed()` function.

I am using jQuery Mobile.

HTML for "feed" page

```
<div data-role="page" id="feed">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1 id="fheader">Header</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="plus">Add to My Teams</a>
        <ul data-role="listview" class="list" data-inset="true" >

        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Function to getFeed

```
    var feedURL="http://www.football365.com/arsenal/rss";
var n = 12;

function getFeed(url, success, n){

    url= feedURL.replace("??", n.toString());

    if(window.navigator.onLine) {
        $.jGFeed(url, function(feeds) {
            // Check for errors
            if(!feeds){
                // there was an error
                return;
            } else {
                localStorage.setItem(url, JSON.stringify(feeds));
                success(feeds.title, feeds.entries);
            }
        },n );
    } else {
        // Get the fall-back...
        var feed = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(url));
        if(feed && feed.length > 0) {
            success(feed.title, feed.entries);
        }
    }
}


$(document).on('pagebeforeshow',function(){

    getFeed(feedURL,function(title,items){
        $("#title").text(title);

        for(var index=0; index<items.length; index+=1){
            $("#list").append(formatItem(items[index]));
        }
        $("#list").listview('refresh');
    },20);
} );
```

Function to find RSS URL based on team

```
function getIndex(teamlist, teamname){
            for(var i = 0; i<teamlist.length; i++){
                if(teamlist[i].teamname == teamname){
                    return i; // if found index will return
                }
            }
            return -1; // if not found -1 will return
        }

        var a = getIndex(teamlist,name); // will give a as 0
        console.log(a);

        feedURL = teamlist[a].rss_url;
        console.log(feedURL);
```

As you can see, the RSS URL for a specific team is found via index in array. Once it has found the array, it assigns it to the feedURL variable. This part works fine

However, when the page opens, it does not take into consideration the change in variable. I need to refresh or rerun the getFeed() function to take into account the new value of feedURL.

Hope this clears things up :) Thanks :)

Comment: What do you mean by *when the page #feed loads*?

Comment: I have a page called with the ID "feed" and when it loads, I need to refresh/ re run the function.

Comment: This question isn't clear. you need to narrow down what exactly your having problems with. It's not practical to go *here's all my code, it's not working, can you figure it all out for me*. Produce a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: What do you mean with "a page called with the ID "feed"???"
Maybe you mean that in your HTML you have a div which ID is "feed" that will be filled with a content of a page loaded using the getFeed() function?

Comment: Im using jQuery mobile and I have a page with the id feed

Comment: Have edited the question, hope it is easier to understand.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run your function when the page has loaded just use:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    getFeed();
};
```

This will run your function when the page has fully rendered and the #feed element is available.